# paintComponent() and actionPerformed() get out of sync for JPanel iplements ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, concurrency, timer, jpanel

I'm trying to make an application that runs an animation. To do this I've got a Jframe that contains my subclass of Jpanel in which the animation runs. Here are my two classes:

Firstly, here's my driver class:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Life {
    public static void main(String[] args){
         JFrame game = new JFrame("Life");

         game.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         game.setSize(500, 500);

         MainPanel mainPanel = new MainPanel();
         game.setContentPane(mainPanel);


         game.setVisible(true);

     }
 }
```

Secondly, here's my subclass of Jpanel:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class MainPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    public MainPanel(){
        super();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        j++;
        g.drawLine(10,10, 20 + i, 20 + i);
        Timer t = new Timer(1000, this);
        t.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        i++;
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Notice that the variable i is incremented each time actionPreformed is called and the variable j is called each time paintComponent is called. What winds up happening is that i starts to be much larger than j and the line drawn by paintComponent seems to grow at a faster and faster rate.

Here are my questions:

- Why does this happen?
- How can I sync things up so that the line gets redrawn each every 1000 ms?
- Given what I'm trying to do, is my approach wrong? Should I be doing things differently?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't start a Swing Timer from within a `paintComponent` method.

This method should do your painting, only your painting and nothing but painting. It should contain absolutely *no* program logic. Understand that you have very limited control over this method since you cannot predict when or if it will be called, how often it will be called. You can't even call it yourself or be guaranteed that when you *suggest* it be called via `repaint()` that it will in fact be called.

Also this method must be fast, as fast possible since anything that slows it down, be it object creation or reading in files will reduce the perceived responsiveness of your GUI, the last thing that you want to see happen.

The solution is to separate the program logic out of that method and into better methods such as your constructor. Repeating code should be in a Swing Timer.

Edit:
You state:

> I just did that to test things out. One more question: What happens if paintComponent, or some thread on which the work in paintComponent depends, takes longer than 1000 ms (or whatever it is) to do its work? The only thing I can think of is having paintComponent paint the progress of the animation so far, rather than waiting for the animation to reach the next step(if that makes any sense). Thoughts?

You should *never* have code in paintComponent that takes that long or even 10's of milliseconds. If there's a risk of something like that happening, then do the drawing in a background thread and to a BufferedImage, and then on the Swing event thread show the BufferedImage in paintComponent method using the `Graphics#drawImage(...)` method.

Comment: Starting the timer in the constructor appears to work better. Does this sound like the right approach?

Comment: @David: also don't increment `j` (that's program logic code) inside of paintComponent but rather do that in the Timer's ActionListener. Also, you never seem to *use* the `j` variable for anything.

Comment: I just did that to test things out. One more question: What happens if paintComponent, or some thread on which the work in paintComponent depends, takes longer than 1000 ms (or whatever it is) to do its work? The only thing I can think of is having paintComponent paint the progress of the animation so far, rather than waiting for the animation to reach the next step(if that makes any sense). Thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

A few minor additions to @HFoE's essential insights:

- A public `start()` method is a handy way to ensure that your view is completely constructed before starting.
- Fields have well-defined [default values](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5), and they [should be `private`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12631933/230513).
- Swing GUI objects should be constructed and manipulated *only* on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).
- Override `getPreferredSize()` and `pack()` the enclosing `Window`.

Revised code:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Life {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            private final JTabbedPane jtp = new JTabbedPane();

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame game = new JFrame("Life");
                game.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                MainPanel mainPanel = new MainPanel();
                game.setContentPane(mainPanel);
                game.pack();
                game.setVisible(true);
                mainPanel.start();
            }
        });
    }

    private static class MainPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

        private Timer t = new Timer(100, this);
        private int i;
        private int j;

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            g.drawLine(10, 10, 20 + i, 20 + i);
        }

        public void start() {
            t.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            i++;
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(500, 500);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A `Timer` by defaults keep on running. Only when you call `setRepeats( false )` it will stop.

So the following lines

```
Timer t = new Timer(1000, this);
t.start();
```

in your `paintComponent` method means that after a few repaints you will have a number of `Timer` instances running, explaining why `i` increases that much faster then `j`.

The solution is of course to move your `Timer` outside the `paintComponent` method, and stick to one `Timer` instance.

Further remarks (which weren't said by the others, not gonna repeat their very useful advise):

- Never override the `paintComponent` method without calling the `super` method
- You shouldn't expose the `ActionListener` interface. Just use an `ActionListener` internally

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 

Two questions: 

1) Why shouldn't i expose the ActionListner interface? 

2) How do I just use an ActionListener internally?

Comment: @David 1) That is an implementation detail. Your class is not meant to be used as an `ActionListener`, so no need to expose it 2) E.g. by using an anonymous class or an inner class